# Is $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + 2$ coercive?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + 2$ coercive?

Im a little stuck on the idea of $x^2 + y^2 = 0$? Can I use this, or not?

Comment: (!) Its in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so, it is coercive, right?

Comment: What is the definition of coercive?

Comment: A continuous function $f(x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is *coercive* if $\lim\limits_{||x||\rightarrow\infty }  f(x) = +\infty.$ (Note that this should hold along any path)

Comment: Of course it is, since $x^2+y^2 = ||x||^2$ and $||x||^2+2 \to \infty$ when $||x||^2 \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

(What Frank wrote in a comment.) You are to prove that for every $M$ there is $R$ such that $f(x)>M$ whenever $\|x\|>R$.

Since $f(x)=\|x\|^2+2$, you can pick $R=\sqrt{M}$ for the desired result.